# need some advice on using getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, selectedindex, getelementsbytagname

Could anyone please explain to me in some details about `getElementsByTagName` and specifically how to properly iterate through the node list returned by `getElementsByTagName`.

Here is my simple script where I want to display a selected index in the alert window but with the use of `getElementsByTagName`. I know it might not be a very good solution to use `getElementsByTagName` in order to get the selected option value but still I would like to use `getElementsByTagName` as it may help me to better understand how this works

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
   function process(){
     var a = document.getElementById('mySelect');
     var res = a.options[a.selectedIndex].text;

     alert(res);
   }
//-->
</script>
```

And here is an HTML snippet:

```
<body>
<select name=""id="mySelect" onchange="process()">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
```

So my question is:

Can anyone tell me how to make this script work using `getElementsByTagName` instead of `getElementById`?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using getElementById to get select and getElementsByTagName to read options

```
function process(){
    var sel = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var opts = sel.getElementsByTagName("option");
    for(var i=0;i<opts.length;i++){
        if(opts[i].selected){
             alert(opts[i].innerHTML);
             break;
        }
    }
}
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/equhex)

Using getElementsByTagName to get select and getElementsByTagName to get options

```
function process(){
    var sels = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    for(var i=0; i<sels.length;i++){
        var opts = sels[i].getElementsByTagName("option");
        for(var j=0;j<opts.length;j++){
            if(opts[j].selected){
                 alert(opts[j].innerHTML);
                 break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using getElementsByTag name to get select and options object

```
function process(){
    var sels = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    for(var i=0; i<sels.length;i++){
        var sel = sels[i];
        alert( sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getElementById returns a single element because ids are supposed to be unique so there should be only one element to return if the given id exists.

getElementsByTagName returns a NodeList object with all the elements with the given tag name.

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
<!--
   function process(){
     var a = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
     var res = a[0].options[a[0].selectedIndex].text;

     alert(res);
   }
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Technically, `getElementsByTagName` returns a NodeList object, which is an array-like object. It has a `.length` property and is indexed, but other array methods like `.pop()` won't work on it. https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList